# Bash/sed - use sed in variable

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to use sed to delete and replace some characters in a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="."
file_extension=".mkv|.avi|.mp4"
files= `find $DIR -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex ".*\.\(mkv\|avi\|mp4\)" -printf "%f\n"`
```

In order to simplify $files, I would like to use $file_extension in it, i.e. change .mkv|.avi|.mp4 to mkv\|avi\|mp4

How can I do that with sed ? Or maybe an easier alternative ?

Comment: Please add a shebang and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: I'd do `files=( "$DIR"/*.{mkv,avi,mp4} )` instead. Storing `find`'s output in a scalar variable is not a good idea, especially when there is no need to use it at all.

Comment: @oguzismail is it better to use ls in a variable ?

Answer (score 1):

No need for `sed`; `bash` has basic substitution operators built in. The basic syntax for a replace-all operation is `${variable//pattern/replacement}`, but unfortunately it can't be nested so you need a helper variable. For clarity, I'll even use two:

```
file_extension_without_dot="${file_extension//./}"           # mkv|avi|mp4
file_extension_regex="${file_extension_without_dot//|/\\|}"  # mkv\|avi\|mp4
files= `find $DIR -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex ".*\.\($file_extension_regex\)" -printf "%f\n"`
```

If your `find` supports it, you could also consider using a different `-regextype` (see `find -regextype help`) so you don't need quite so many backslashes anymore.